# Anonymous checkout with UC and PayPal WPS not working

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

I'm trying to use PayPal WPS with my Ubercart, and I'd like for the user to not have to create an account on my site before placing an order. However, if I enable "anonymous checkout", then go through the process of a PayPal transaction, when PayPal redirects back to my site, it never creates a new user account.

It successfully updates the order with the payment from PayPal, but doesn't create a new user with which to associate the order, so all the user information is lost.

What could I be missing here? I believe I've followed all the steps on the UC side and on the PayPal side to enable anonymous checkout, but it still fails to automatically create a new user based on the PayPal transaction.

Answer (score 2):

hey, i had this issue too, what solved it for me was going into the DB, checking users table and making sure the 1st row which is for anonymous users has the primary key as 0, try this if it doesnt let me know, Chris

Comment: Yes, the first user has an ID of 0, and no information in any of the other fields.  In fact, after checkout, the order gets assigned to the anonymous user (#0), but that's precisely what I don't want. It should create a new user based on the customer's email, then automatically log that user in.

Comment: ye it should do, i had this issue but i solved it, i dont have access to the site i did it on till later so ill get back to you later on this if no one else beats me ;)

Comment: sorry Dmitry, thought id posted my reply, i looked at my notes and to get it sorted i did the change i suggested and it worked, im not sure what else to suggest, have you tried drupal.org?